# Coverting string to decimal

Tags: c#, .net

how to convert string to decimal upto 3 places?

my string will be like this

```
striing aa = "22.333"
string  bb = "22"
string cc = "22.4444"
```

how to convert this to decimal

Comment: Have you even tried putting your question title into Google?  Or the search on here?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i m stucked here. pls help. i will lose jobe for this today .. new to asp.net

Comment: i need to know it for 3 decimal places. my brain is blank now..

Comment: What? You loose your job because you can't parse these strings to decimal?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert and round in one line - and one line to take care of localization:

```
string cc = "22.4444";
IFormatProvider provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
decimal ccDecimal = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(cc,provider), 3);
```

Will return `22.444`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with decimal.Parse (ToDecimal) Method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hf9z3s65%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
string value = "22.333";
decimal d = decimal.Parse(s);
```

Comment: i m stucked here. pls help. i will lose jobe for this today .. new to asp.net i need to know it for 3 decimal places. my brain is blank now.. –

Comment: Than you can use the TryParse Method:
value = "22.333";
if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out number))
   Console.WriteLine(number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse '{0}'.", value);

Comment: This code is *not* safe - it will fail in cultures that use `,` as a decimal point. A lot of European countries do. The compiler will even give a warning about this. The duplicate question shows the correct way to parse using the InvariantCulture

Answer (score 0):

First you can convert your String to a Decimal Value:

```
var convertDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(value);
```

Afterwards you can round it up, if it is longer:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx

As far as i know, you cant "convert" the String to a decimal with 3 Positions, if its smaller, because it is saved with the zeros anyway

Comment: This code is *not* safe - it will fail in cultures that use `,` as a decimal point. A lot of European countries do. The compiler will even give a warning about this. The duplicate question shows the correct way to parse using the InvariantCulture

Comment: The other solution just surrounds the statement with a try-catch block. For me they where not part of the solution, because it is a general Problem your might encounter when parsing non-basic types. But you are write. I edit the answer.

Comment: No other answer uses try/catch. The accepted answer in the duplicate uses CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. In fact, both the compiler *and* Resharper give a warning with such code, suggesting to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: a i see i was to fast...

Answer (score 0):

3 places can be achieved with `Math.Round`. Safest string conversion would be the `TryParse` method:

```
 string srcString = "123.45123";

 decimal outDecimal;

 if (decimal.TryParse(srcString, out outDecimal))
 {
     // conversion is successful, so you can use outDecimal variable  
     outDecimal = decimal.Round(outDecimal, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); 
 }
```

Comment: This code is *not* safe - it will fail in cultures that use `,` as a decimal point. A lot of European countries do. The compiler will even give a warning about this. The duplicate question shows the correct way to parse using the InvariantCulture

Comment: Yes, I forgot about culture

Answer (score 0):

You could doing something like this

```
    string aa = "22.333";
    string bb = "22";
    string cc = "22.4444";

    decimal d = decimal.Parse(aa);
    decimal e = decimal.Parse(bb);
    decimal f = decimal.Parse(cc);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0.000}", d));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0.000}", e));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0.000}", f));
```

Comment: Well, you should test it.  It won't.  You can't format a string using a number format: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gIC4oS

Comment: This code is *not* safe - it will fail in cultures that use `,` as a decimal point. A lot of European countries do. The compiler will even give a warning about this. The duplicate question shows the correct way to parse using the InvariantCulture

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
string value;
decimal number;

value = "1,643.57";
if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out number))
   Console.WriteLine(number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse '{0}'.", value);
```

Comment: This code is *not* safe - it will fail in cultures that use `,` as a decimal point. A lot of European countries do. The compiler will even give a warning about this. The duplicate question shows the correct way to parse using the InvariantCulture